# Building a standalone executable for nodejs application with C++ addons

Tags: c++, node.js, build, native, node-webkit

I'm currently building C++ addons for nodejs so that I could expose some of the C++ API via websockets. This API lets the clients talk to composite devices connected to a PC (or even Pi). Since it will be deployed on PCs I'd like to bundle it as a standalone app. I've used node webkit (nw + nw-gyp) for POC. This works fine however moving forward I'd like to break the UI layer as a separate deployable and the layer which exposes websockets API as a separate deployable.

But currently when you build an app with node-webkit it includes the browser as well which makes a "big" deployable. I really don't need browser included. Is there anyway to say to node webkit don't include the browser? I've looked at jxcore as a possible alternative but it's still a very young project and I'm not sure if it can support C++ addons either. Is there a better way to building standalone node apps (with no UI) which has native addons as dependency?

Comment: as long as you keep the .node files (c,c++ addons) outside (consider them as DLLs those you are shipping with your binary) jxcore is a good choice

Comment: If I can use node-gyp to build my addons and then use jxcore to build the rest and add the addons outside the built binary I would be happy to do that. Only thing is I'm not sure if jxcore is mature enough but definitely worth a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One more simple solution to this is to use webcomponents in the browser, JRPC on the network (but abstracting objects). Nodejs can interface C++ using SWIG and that closes the loop between the browser and C++.

This approach avoids using heavy frameworks and dependencies.

A complete example is available in [this microapp](https://github.com/flatmax/lit-jrpc-swig). The basics of it are to wrap your C++ using SWIG so that nodejs can require it :

```
%module "swigCNodejs"
%{
#include "Test.H"
%}

%include <std_string.i>
%include "Test.H"
```

Then compile that wrapper to nodejs modules which are executed in nodejs like so :

```
var libSwigCNodejs = require('../swig/.libs/libSwigCNodejs');
let test = new libSwigCNodejs.Test;
```

Expose that class over the network to the browser using JRPC+JRPC-OO :

```
let JRPCTools = require('@flatmax/jrpc-oo/JRPCTools');

// get a class to expose over the network
let TestClass = require('./TestClass').TestClass;

// note TestClass2 inherits TestClass
tc=new TestClass; // this class will be used over js-JRPC

// start the server and add the class.
var JrpcServer=new JRPCTools.JRPCServer(9000); // start a server on port 9000
JrpcServer.addClass(tc); // setup the class for remote use over the network
```

Then in the browser implement your webcomponent to inherit the JRPCClient class like so :

```
class Test extends JRPCClient {...};
```

You can now execute the C++ from the browser over the network.

Answer (score 0):

If you built a Node.js extension/plug-in and you don't need the browser for the wrapper, why are you using NW.js? If you're simply trying to convert a Node.js script to an EXE, use `pkg` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg).